# C — How would I make my stack completely dynamic?

Tags: c, stack, malloc, push, realloc

Currently my code uses a stack and pushes a user entered string into the stack one by one. However I would like to make it dynamic, what would I malloc/realloc, I know I'm missing something completely obvious but I guess I have tunnel vision... help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXSIZE 100
char a [MAXSIZE];
char * p = a;
int top = -1;

void push ( char n )
{
    if ( top == 99)
    {
        printf( "stack overflow");
        return;
    }
    top+=1;
    a[top] = n;
}


/*  Function to delete an element from the stack */
void pop(){
    if(top == -1)
        printf("Stack is Empty");
    else
        top-=1;

}

char *inputString(FILE* fp, size_t size){
    //The size is extended by the input with the value of the provisional
    char *str;
    int ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);//size is start size
    if(!str)return str;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n'){
        str[len++]=ch;
        if(len==size){
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size+=16));
            if(!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++]='\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
}
int balanced (char * m){
    int size = sizeof(m);
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<=size; ++i){
        push(m[i]);
    }
}
int main(void){
    char *m;

    printf("input string : ");
    m = inputString(stdin, 10);
    printf("%s\n", m);
    balanced(m);
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=sizeof(a);++i){
        printf("\n%c", a[i]);
    }
    free(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tunnel vision can be a good thing. Clear away all of the extraneous code, anything not *directly* relevant to your problem. Make a stack of `int`, use hard-coded values instead of user input, *simplify*. Then you'll probably see the answer. Or at least reduce the amount of work you're asking us to do.

Comment: The only significant change between this and the previous edition of the question is `for (i = 0; i <= MAXSIZE; ++i)` has become `for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(a); ++i)`.  This is near as dammit the same question asked twice; please don't do that!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, this is what you are supposed to do.

```
struct Stack
{
    char c;
    struct Stack *next;
}*stack = NULL;

char pop()
{
    if(stack == NULL)
    {
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    c = stack -> c;
    struct Stack * temp = stack;
    stack = stack -> next;
    free(temp);

    return c;
}

void push(char c)
{
    struct Stack * temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    temp -> next = NULL;
    temp -> c = c;

    if (stack == NULL)
        stack = temp;
    else
    {
        temp -> next = stack;
        stack = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: stack overflow error message is when stack exceeds given size on push

Comment: @Ulterior, Ok. I did n't notice that. Just corrected now.

Comment: A linked list is one option, but I'm not sure it's the best option for a stack of single characters.  I think a dynamically allocated array would be more sensible.